# Prevent partial Tapjacking - Android

Tags: android, security, motionevent

I'm working to improve the security of an application and prevent Tapjacking.  For this we have made use of:

```
filterTouchesWhenObscured = "true"
```

It seems that with this we have managed to protect the application against a situation in which the view was completely covered (`FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED`) but not yet one in which it was partially covered (`FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED`).

I really don't know how to handle this last situation, I have read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED) the meaning of the flag but I don't find documentation about how to resolve the situation.

Anyone has faced this issue before or knows how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: Tapjacking has been blocked by the OS since Android 4.1 or so. App code for a window cannot both see touch events and pass them along to underlying windows. Are you able to reproduce a tapjacking attack?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have read about it but also saw links like this one: https://www.xda-developers.com/how-tapjacking-made-a-return-with-android-marshmallow-and-nobody-noticed/ talking about Tapjacking in Marshmallow. Anyway, I didn't reproduce it personally but a team did, using the app Visium TapJacking I think. The thing is that it only happens when they cover the view partially, and I don't know if they are touching outside that section and considering it still dangerous (would it still be?). Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who have the same problem finally I simply checked the flag `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED`. To do so I extended the RelativeLayout class (you could do it with any view class) an overrided the method `onFilterTouchEventForSecurity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(MotionEvent event) {
    if (((event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED)
            || (event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED) == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED){
        return false;
    }

    return super.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(event);
}
```

The flag `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED` will be returned to `true` even if the touch is made outside the partially covered area (as long as there are some part of the view covered), so it's very useful to make security checks.

The bad part is that it's included in Api 29, so you'll have to include that version in your app in order to use it.

Comment: MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_PARTIALLY_OBSCURED has been there but hidden (@hide) since API 24, so this will work on API 24+.

Comment: Not practical -- because you actually have to extend everything just to add this.

Comment: For each view we are using, we have to do so ? We are using many layouts so those all required this ? We have to make custom class for parent layout of each layout xml right ?